# Using Termux to Backup Android's Contact List

Tags: contacts, backup, automation, terminal, termux

In Termux's website's main page, they write (among other stuff):

> "use rsync to store backups of your contact list on a remote server"

This makes me wonder:
Android's Contact List is stored in an SQLite DB, which is a file on the phone's internal storage.
rsync synchronizes files.

So If I understand the required implementation behind this idea,
then what they mean by the quoted sentence, is that you can simply synchronize the whole SQLite DB file, to a remote server.

The problem is:
What happens when the day comes, and you need to **Restore** your Contacts DB?

I assume that Android will not let you copy the SQLite DB file that you saved aside, over the current (new, and empty) Contact List's SQLite DB file,
So how will we do the restoration?

I hope someone understood their idea in this sentence..

Comment: It is simple: On file level you need root permissions for creating the backup of the contact SQLite db file and you need root permissions for restoring a backup.

Comment: Termux provides an [API](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Termux:API) to retrieve contacts list. You don't need to backup/restore the database file.

Comment: @Robert Thank you, so without root (on my device, not inside Termux which of course has root) it's completely impossible?

Comment: @IrfanLatif The `Termux-contact-list` command in Termux API enables Reading the Contacts List, but what about Writing it back?

Comment: @spaceman I didn't use the API but it must be working on both sides. Just as any contacts backup app works

Comment: @IrfanLatif according to the `termux-contact-list` command documentation, it only Reads, not Writes.. https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Termux-contact-list

Comment: @spaceman may be. I'm not sure about that.